# calling a new() function from another class

Tags: vb.net

I've made two windows forms and imported the class of one into the other. The trouble I'm having is calling the New() method in the imported class to pass the parameters to the class methods in the imported class. Here's the basic code I use in the main class. I use Visual Studio 2017, and it's not recognizing the New() method in the imported class when I call it. Perhaps someone may be able to tell me what I'm doing wrong?

```
Private Sub Backup_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Me.Load
    LstBxPlanBackup.SelectedIndex = -1
    GetPlans()
    New(LstBoxBaseBackup.SelectedIndex, "", ..\watcher.txt, Backup, Watcher.Prompt)
End Sub
```

Comment: What do you mean by "imported"?

Comment: I made a namespace for the other class, and imported it into the class I want to call from.

Comment: `Sub New()` is a Form's constructor (where you usually find `InitializeComponent()`). `Dim ANewForm as MyFormClass = new MyFormClass(LstBoxBaseBackup.SelectedIndex, "", "..\watcher.txt", Backup, Watcher.Prompt)`. `MyFormClass` must have a constructor that acceps those parameters. I think you shoud define that Form in a separate class. It's easier to handle.

Comment: Hey Jimi, I'm using the code you listed in another question on FSW. It didn't occur to me that you meant you can define the class with the main class one is working with. I went the extra step and made a separate class in a new Windows Form and then imported. I tried it defining the class within the main Form, and see that it works that way too.

Comment: Well, you're talking about two **Forms** here. A `FileSystemWatcher` is not a Form. Anyway, it's an usual design pattern to keep classes in separate files and let these classes be as much independent as possible. This way, you could always re-use a specialized class in another project without changing it every time. Use Properties and Methods to configure your class. Generic constructors work as well. Avoid any modifications that ties that class to a specific implementation and context. Think about the `.Net Framework` classes and how they work.

Answer (score 0):

> Sub New() is a Form's constructor (where you usually find InitializeComponent()). Dim ANewForm as MyFormClass = new MyFormClass(LstBoxBaseBackup.SelectedIndex, "", "..\watcher.txt", Backup, Watcher.Prompt). MyFormClass must have a constructor that acceps those parameters. I think you shoud define that Form in a separate class. It's easier to handle.

I think your response there was the answer to question. It may be worth noting, though, for those like me that are new to programming that it's possible to define a class within a class, and one doesn't have to make a separate form to define a class and use it. Your suggested statement solves the problem of how to pass the new information to the required class. Thanks!